# How to test button click in child component when testing using Jest Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

So I have a parent component called InventoryView and a child component InventoryBase that basically renders data sent to it by InventoryView. So the problem I keep running into is that I need to test if the Update button in InventoryBase is calling `handleUpdate()`. HandleUpdate should only be called if input values have actually been changed. I need to test whether or not `handleUpdate()` is being called if input changes or not.

So the button first called --> `handleClick()` which looks at the inputs and gathers data and then calls `handleUpdate()` which propagates to InventoryView. When I test `handleUpdate()` and make sure if the inputs have changed, it says `handleUpdate()` has been called zero times. Since I have changed one of the inputs the `handleUpdate()` and `handleClick()` both should be called once. But they are being called 0 times. I `console.log` the `prev` and `cur` input values in `handleClick()` so when I simulate a click on the button those values are being printed meaning `handleClick()` is being triggered but the click on mock is not being registered..??? I am not sure what is happening here.

InventoryView:

```
 render() {
    return(
        <InventoryBase
            tableHeadings={inventoryViewUpdate.tableHeadings}
            tableTitle={inventoryViewUpdate.tableTitle}
            tableBody={this.state.tableBody}
            tableFooter={this.state.tableFooter}
            handleUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
            lastUpdated={this.state.lastUpdated}
            endOfDay={true} />
    );
}
```

InventoryBase: inventoryBase.updateBtn === 'UPDATE' which is the ID I use to simulate the button.

```
handleClick = (inputIds, prevVals) => {
    let change = false;
    let curVals = [];
    let update = {
        inputUpdate: [],
        timeUpdate: this.updateDate()
    };
    for (let i in inputIds) {
        let pkg = {
            id: inputIds[i],
            value: document.getElementById(inputIds[i]).value
        }
        curVals[i] = pkg.value;
        update.inputUpdate.push(pkg);
    }

    for (let i in curVals) {
        if (curVals[i] != prevVals[i]) change = true;
    }
    if (change === false) return;
    console.log(curVals); <-- prints ['2', '4']
    console.log(prevVals); <-- prints ['4', '4']
    this.props.handleUpdate(update); <----- call handleUpdate here if inputs have changed
}

render() {
    let inputIds = [];
    let prevVals = [];
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
        <Aux>
            <Paper className={classes.root}>
                <div style={{ float: 'right', width: "132px" }}>
                    <div style={{ display: 'flex', align: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                        <Button type="button" id={inventoryBase.updateBtn} variant="contained" onClick={() => this.handleClick(inputIds, prevVals)} className={classes.updateBtn}>
                            <span>
                                <Autorenew style={{
                                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                                    marginRight: '8px'
                                }} />
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <Typography style={{ marginBottom: '8px' }} className={classes.btnText}>{inventoryBase.updateBtn}</Typography>
                            </span>
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                ....
                ..... more code
            </Paper>
        </Aux>
    );
}
```

InventoryView.test.js:

```
const STORE = createStore();

describe('InventoryBase', () => {
    let wrapper;
    let props;
    beforeEach(() => {
        props = {
            inventory: inventory,
            packages: packages,
            branchLockers: branchLockers,
            updateInventory: jest.fn(),
            handleUpdate: jest.fn()
        }
        wrapper = mount(
            <Provider store={STORE}>
                <InventoryViewComponent {...props}/>  
            </Provider> , { attachTo: document.body }
        );
    });

    test('Should update last updated time if input values have changed', () => {
        document.getElementById('Envelop_1').value = '2'

        wrapper.find('#UPDATE').at(0).simulate('click');
        wrapper.update();

        expect(props.handleUpdate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

});
```

Comment: Resolved this issue by testing each component individually and passing in mock data.